# Read value of variable with Javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I'm using Javassist to get the Fields on a Class, using the following code:

```
for (CtField ctf : ctclass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(ctf.getName());
}
```

Thus, all the variables of the class to which I am accessing, are displayed on the screen and this works well.

What I want to know is it is possible to access the value of any of these variables?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need an instance of the class to do so. Do you have one?

Comment: I'm trying to access a service that runs on Jboss Server, from another service that runs on the same server, specifically with JAIN SLEE.
Thus, I can't get the instance because I am accessing from another service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it wasn't' necessary to use Javassist. With Java Reflect was enough, in this way:

```
String tempClassPath = tempDirPath + serviceName + sbbJarCmpt;
```

Where tempClassPath is the Path location of the service .jar file.

Now, with Java Reflect:

```
URL[] classes = {new File(tempClassPath).toURI().toURL()};
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (classes, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class fieldClass = Class.forName(className, true, child);
```

With this, I get an instance of the class and I can continue with the rest of the process.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get the values of these variables is if you have an instance of the object for which you want to get the values for (since different instances may have different values).

```
Object instance = ...
...
for (CtField ctf : ctclass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    Field f = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(ctf.getName());
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object value = f.get(instance);
}
```

If you're trying to access static fields then you don't need the instance and you can just do `f.get(null)` in the code above.

Also, if you are using this for some sort of profiling along with java instrumentation or something like that and you do not have any instances of the objects you are inspecting, a viable strategy would be to add a `static` field that is a `Collection` of instances to each class (using javassist) and then transform all constructors (using `insertAfter`) to add `this` to that field. Then you can use the same reflection method in my example to get this new field from each class that you care about and thus you will have a reference to all instances.

Comment: I'm trying to access a service that runs on Jboss Server, from another service that runs on the same server, specifically with JAIN SLEE. Thus, I can't get the instance because I am accessing from another service.  
I should also say that all the fields which I want to get the value, are static fields.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the code I posted except instead of using `f.get(instance)` you need to do `f.get(null)`. To get the `Field` in the first place though you'll need a reference to the `Class` object for that class and since you don't have an instance you can't do `instance.getClass()`. You can try using `Class.forName(...)` to get that if you don't have that class already. However, if you're just looking up constants then you don't need the `Field` at all and can use `CtField.getConstantValue()`.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help!
You're right when you say that I don't have an instance, so I can't do instance.getClass().
When you say that I can use Class.forName(...), this is possible even when the class to which I want to access is in another service?
I can't just use CtField.getConstantValue() because the fields that I want to get the value of, are static String, but no final fields, and in that case the method will return null.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the tools/environment you are working with so I am not sure if `Class.forName(...)` will get you what you want. If the class is loaded on a remote VM (what it sounds like from what you are describing) then it will probably not work (it will load the class in your VM but you want the one that's already been loaded not a new one). Either way, you will need to get the `Class` object you care about by some means in the environment you are working with to do what you want.